# Comment out CSS stylesheet dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css

I have built pretty heavy light and dark modes with localstorage for a website.
Switching from one to the other is seamless and both look amazing.
Yet, i have flickering issues when navigating the dark mode.

Both style sheets reside in this order upwards in my header.php

```
    <link id="light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="day" href="https://example.com/public/css/main.css">
    <link id="dark" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="night" href="https://example.com/public/css/night.css">
```

The localstorage switches are handled with javascript downwards in the same file.

After trying a million things, turns out to be that when i comment out the first stylesheet mentioned above, the flickering disappears and the browsing is seamless.

So my question would be: How can i comment out the first stylesheet line with some javascript command that would be added to the localstorage section? Or is there another way to comment out that stylesheet dynamically?

Here ist the localstorage function where i would need it to be inside:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("light").href = localStorage.getItem('light');
document.getElementById("dark").href = localStorage.getItem('dark');

function dayoff() {
document.getElementById("light").href = 'https://example.com/public/css/night.css';
    localStorage.setItem( 'light', 'https://example.com/public/css/night.css' );
document.getElementById("light").href = 'https://example.com/public/css/night.css';
    localStorage.setItem( 'dark', 'https://example.com/public/css/night.css' );
document.getElementById("logo").src = 'https://example.com/public/img/toplogo-night.png';
    location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would do that on server side. By default user has some style and the other is not even present on an HTML tag. User selects another style and from PHP you keep a cookie (database field would be better) and change the CSS.

Comment: Can you show your complete function?

Comment: Sure, there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep what mode the user is using (light or dark)

```
localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light or dark');
```

Then you should add the stylesheet based on what mode the user is using.

Your function

```
function dayoff() {
   // toggle function 
   if(localStorage.getItem("mode") === null || localStorage.getItem("mode") == "light"){
       localStorage.setItem("mode", "dark");
   }
   else{
       localStorage.setItem("mode", "light");
   }
   location.reload();
}
if(localStorage.getItem("mode") === null){
   // first time visitors
    $('head').append('<link id="light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/public/css/main.css">');
}
else{
   // returning users
   if(localStorage.getItem('mode') == "light"){
      $('head').append('<link id="light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/public/css/main.css">');
   }
   else{
      $('head').append('<link id="dark" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/public/css/dark.css">');
   }
}
```

Comment: As it is jquery, can i add it inside of the javascript function that handles the local storage ? Let me add the function i use to "turn off the lights" to my question.

Comment: I assume you use js localstorage? then yes

Comment: But there needs to be a standard mode (light preferably) for first time visitors. Either one or the other should be active. If no style is set, the site willl look weird, wouldn't it ? Thanks for the time by the way.

Comment: check my updated answer, is this what your looking for?

Comment: Amazing, just parsing it. Would you like to join me in my chatroom for a few minutes, this thing is really important to me. I could show you exactly how the whole thing looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204563/discussion-between-jbadminton-and-john-kerby).